# Why does Git in windows shows different SHA-1 for same content?

Tags: git

When piping output from standard input, the result is

```sh
$ echo "Apple Pie" | git hash-object --stdin
157cb7be4778a9cfad23b6fb514e364522167053
```

But the exact same text, when put inside a file produces a different hash.

```sh
$ git cat-file -p 23991897e13e47ed0adb91a0082c31c82fe0cbe5
Apple Pie
```

I have tried the same commands in WSL and native Linux installation, and the results are consistent and the hash is always same.

```
23991897e13e47ed0adb91a0082c31c82fe0cbe5
```

Comment: Encoding might be different? I'm not sure how to compare stdin and file's content byte-wise

Comment: Also, `autocrlf` setting may be a factor.